# How to debug greasemonkey scripts in firebug

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug, greasemonkey

How do you set up firebug to debug a grease monkey script?

I've installed firebug on both my laptop and pc. On my laptop it works fine, all the grease monkey scripts are listed under the script tab. However on my pc they don't appear which is unfortunate because I want to work on my pc. They've both got the same versions of firebug, firefox and windows and I have tested them on the same webpage. I can't see any difference in the settings between the 2 machines so am baffled as to why one is working but not the other. Please does anyone have any suggestions as to how to sort this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
debugger;
```

in your code if you haven't already. I've had this work in the past, though it can be finicky.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this by creating a new profile in firefox.